# CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex doesn't return keywords and other Photos.app fields

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, ciimage

In Photos.app on OS X I have specified a title, keywords and a description on a photo in my library. On iOS, I retrieved an PHAsset using the regular fetching methods.

Then using `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`, I fetched the metadata for the photo. The metadata is correct (it has all GPS and EXIF data), however it doesn't include any of those custom fields.

The keywords and other fields are definitely on the device as I can search Photos.app on iOS by those fields and the photo is found.

Is there another way to access these fields, or perhaps there is a bug with `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`?

```
if let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) {
    print(metadata)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That info is in the Photos app's database on the device (which is synced with Photos on OS X), not embedded in the individual media files. There's no public API for querying those fields in the Photos framework — sounds like a good thing to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex after iOS 11 update

I also have the same problem. My app worked in iOS 10.3.3 and after the update to iOS 11 I'm unable to get the metadata information (description field) of a PNG file using the CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex function. The description field of the metadata (PNG file) is empty. I already reported the bug to apple but I've not answer since september 27/2017.

The following code worked on iOS 10.3.3 (not working in iOS 11, iOS 11.0.1,  iOS 11.0.2, iOS 11.0.3, iOS 11.1,... iOS 11.2)

NSString pngFile = @"Demo.PNG" // Demo.PNG = any PNG file with description

```
CGImageSourceRef imgSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pngFile], NULL);
NSDictionary *metaDataDict =  CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSrc, 0, nil));
if (imgSrc!=nil) {
    NSDictionary *metaDataDict =  (__bridge NSDictionary *)(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSrc, 0, nil));
    // Release imgSrc
    CFRelease(imgSrc);
}
```

(see details in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90958)